# Client side templating

Tags: javascript

I have a task to make a form to send to server with this condition:
Templating:
building form in browser should be implemented with client
templating based on model (viewmodel), represented as  json :

```
{some json}
```

As a templating engine U can use hogan.js for example.

So I found that hogan.js is a compiler for the Mustache templating language.
And right now i just don't know what to begin with.
Does viewmodel refer to model veiw controller?
Should mustashe be used with node.js?
[I found mustashe man link](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) But once again there is no word about model view or controller there

Comment: you can try with [backbone JS - js MVC](http://backbonejs.org/) (with model, controller e view) and [underscore JS - helper](http://underscorejs.org/) (with template Engine)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of frameworks out there who do the job like:

- [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)
- [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)
- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- and many [more](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396)

What you essentially do is providing data objects to the template engine. Based on the logic you define in the template you render the page without the need to clutter the application logic and the layout.

In order to find the right template engine for your application you might want to check out: http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/ Here you can define what kind of engine you are looking for and the website shows you the most suitable library.

Comment: Let's say i chose Mustache, and Hogan.js is a compiler for the Mustache templating language.Does it mean that without hogan Mustashe won't work?

Comment: No, Mustache could be used without Hogan. Hogan just uses the Mustache syntax.

Comment: So what is the point of using hogan if it can be done with Mustashe alone?

Comment: Hogan is an alternative to Mustache.js for minimalists who just want a template engine and nothing more. If you Google "mustache vs hogan" you see lots of site comparing both.

Comment: We can use it only with Node.js, can't we?

Comment: No you van also include it as script tag as shown on the Hogan website